# How to find all subsets whose sum adds up to the value of a target value using dynamic programming in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, backtracking, subset-sum

So I have been trying to do a variant of the subset sum problem, which I want to do using dynamic programming. So what I am aiming for is for example, to have an input of

`m = 25 // Target value`

```
n = 7 // Size of input set
```

and the input set to be for example `{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 25}`. So the wanted output would be something like

```
{1, 3, 4, 7, 10} and {25}.
```

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Get input sequence
    int n = 7;    // Size of input set
    int m = 25;    // Target value
    int *S;   // Input set
    int **C;   // Cost table
    int i,j,potentialSum,leftover;
    S=(int*) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    C=malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int*));
    for (int rows = 0; rows<=m; rows++) {
        C[rows] = malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int));
    }
    if (!S || !C)
    {
        printf(" FAILED %d\n",__LINE__);
        exit(0);
    }
    S[0] = 0;
    S[1] = 1;
    S[2] = 3;
    S[3] = 4;
    S[4] = 6;
    S[5] = 7;
    S[6] = 10;
    S[7] = 25;

    // Initialize table for DP
    C[0][0]=0;  // DP base case

    // For each potential sum, determine the smallest index such
    // that its input value is in a subset to achieve that sum.
    for (potentialSum=1; potentialSum<=m; potentialSum ++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            leftover=potentialSum-S[j];      // To be achieved with other values
            if (leftover<0)                  // Too much thrown away
                continue;
            if (C[leftover][0] == (-1))           // No way to achieve leftover
                continue;
            if (C[leftover][0]<j)               // Indices are included in
                break;                         // ascending order.
        }
        C[potentialSum][0]=(j<=n) ? j : (-1);
    }

    // Output the input set
    printf("  i   S\n");
    printf("-------\n");
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%3d %3d\n",i,S[i]);

    // Output the DP table
    printf("\n\n  i   C\n");
    printf("-------\n");
    for (i=0;i<=m;i++)
        printf("%3d %3d\n",i,C[i][0]);

    if (C[m][m]==(-1))
        printf("No solution\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nSolution\n\n");
        printf("(Position) i   S\n");
        printf("------------------\n");
        for (i=m;i>0;i-=S[C[i][0]])
            printf("        %3d %3d\n",C[i][0],S[C[i][0]]);
    }
}
```

This will output the following

```
 i   S
-------
  0   0
  1   1
  2   3
  3   4
  4   6
  5   7
  6  10
  7  25

  i   C
-------
  0   0
  1   1
  2  -1
  3   2
  4   2
  5   3
  6   4
  7   3
  8   3
  9   4
 10   4
 11   4
 12   5
 13   4
 14   4
 15   5
 16   5
 17   5
 18   5
 19   6
 20   5
 21   5
 22   6
 23   6
 24   6
 25   6

Solution

(Position) i   S
------------------
          6  10
          5   7
          3   4
          2   3
          1   1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

My problem is that I can only output one solution, and that is the solution that needs the smaller values and goes up to 25, so when 25 is used it isn't in the  solution. The `C` array in the code is a 2-D array, since I thought I could maybe do another backtrace while computing the first one? I couldn't figure out how to do so, so I left `C[i][0]` fixed to the first column, just to demonstrate a single solution. Any tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I found a solution using Python, but the problem is solved recursively, which I don't think helps me, but that code is [here](http://txt.do/xc1t).

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Please don't post links to code and the output. If those links break, the comments and answers posted here won't make sense. Post the code and output in the question itself.

Comment: @RSahu I apologize, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand your code. But here is a `C` code which finds all the subsets that sum to `target`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 25 };     //-- notice that the input array is zero indexed
int n = 7;
int target = 25;
int dp[8][26];

int solutions[1 << 7][8];           //-- notice that the number of subsets could be exponential in the length of the input array a.
int sz[1 << 7];                     //-- sz[i] is the length of subset solutions[i]
int cnt = 0;                        //-- number of subsets




void copy(int srcIdx, int dstIdx){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sz[srcIdx]; i++)
        solutions[dstIdx][i] = solutions[srcIdx][i];
    sz[dstIdx] = sz[srcIdx];
}

//-- i, and j are indices of dp array
//-- idx is the index of the current subset in the solution array
void buildSolutions(int i, int j, int idx){
    if (i == 0 || j == 0) return;           // no more elements to add to the current subset

    if (dp[i - 1][j] && dp[i - 1][j - a[i]]){   // we have two branches
        cnt++;                                  // increase the number of total subsets
        copy(idx, cnt);                         // copy the current subset to the new subset. The new subset does not include a[i]
        buildSolutions(i - 1, j, cnt);          //find the remaining elements of the new subset 

        solutions[idx][sz[idx]] = a[i];         // include a[i] in the current subset
        sz[idx]++;                              // increase the size of the current subset
        buildSolutions(i - 1, j - a[i], idx);   // calculate the remaining of the current subset
    }
    else if (dp[i - 1][j - a[i]]){              // we only have one branch
        solutions[idx][sz[idx]] = a[i];         // add a[i] to the current subset     
        sz[idx]++;
        buildSolutions(i - 1, j - a[i], idx);     // calculate the remaining of the current subset
    }
    else buildSolutions(i - 1, j, idx);           // a[i] is not part of the current subset

}

int main(){

    int i, j;

    // initialize dp array to 0
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= target; j++) dp[i][j] = 0;

    //-- filling the  dp array
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        dp[i][0] = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= target; j++){
            if (j < a[i])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
            else
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] || dp[i - 1][j - a[i]];
        }
    }

    //-- building all the solutions
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(sz); i++) sz[i] = 0;     //-- initializing the sz array to 0
    buildSolutions(n, target, 0);


    //-- printing all the subsets
    for (i = 0; i <= cnt; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < sz[i]; j++){
            printf("%d ", solutions[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

If you have any questions about the code, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm still trying to understand your code. If I have any questions I'll be sure to ask.